# Defining a controller - angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am doing it this way.

**Method 1:**

```
var app = angular.module('MyModule', ['ngDialog']);
app.controller('MyController', function ($scope,ngDialog) {
///
});
```

but i see a lot like the below kind in articles

**Method 2:**

```
app.controller('MyController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
///
}]);
```

Please help me understand why is $scope mentioned twice in method 2. 
Is method 1, a good practice. If not, in what cases will it fail.

Comment: Read this also; https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method 2 is used to prevent minification bugs. In Production when you usually minify your JS/CSS files, the variables' names change to reduce bytes and make the files lighter.

AngularJS relies on DI, which means that it knows which service/provider to inject to your controllers/services according to the name. If it sees `$httpProvider`, it knows to inject `$httpProvider`. Once minifaction takes place, the naming will change from:

```
app.controller('MyController', function (a,b) { //a, b is the change
///
});
```

Or something of that sort.

Using Method 2, you specify the names as strings, and using those strings AngularJS knows what to inject despite the fact that the minification changed the variables' names.

You can read more about this [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di).

Answer (score 2):

The recommended way of declaring Controllers is using the array notation:

```
someModule.controller('MyController', ['$scope', 'dep1', 'dep2', function($scope, dep1, dep2) {
  ...
  $scope.aMethod = function() {
    ...
  }
  ...
}]);
```

**Dependency Annotation**
There are three ways of annotating your code with service name information:

```
Using the inline array annotation (preferred)
Using the $inject property annotation
Implicitly from the function parameter names (has caveats)
```

Among These three,Using the **inline array** annotation is preferred approach.And
the last is simplest way to get hold of the dependencies is to assume 
that the function parameter names are the names of the dependencies.
**Advantage** of **implicitly from the function parameter** names approach is that there's no array of names to keep in sync with the function parameters. You can also freely reorder dependencies.And **disadvantage** is  `If you plan to minify your code, your service names will get renamed and break your app.`

Source: [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di)